# How to get an isomorphic graph from another in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

Good morning, everyone.

I am currently doing a unit test of a function that processes graphs and it should give similar results in front of isomorphic graphs. So, I would like to output only an isomorphic graph from a networkx graph, but I can't find if that functionality exists. [Here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html) it talks about the checks needed to see if two graphs are isomorphic, but not about how to get one.

Is there such functionality in the networkx library or does anyone know how to get one?

Comment: You could use the same graph and change some nodes names to be a random string no?

Comment: Does that changes the edges connections and attributes as well? @Dr.Prof.Patrick

Comment: no, that's why i suggested it, if you begin playing around with the edge connections you might destroy the isomorphism :)

Comment: But it should change edges as well. For example if I have two nodes (0 and 1) and the edge is the tuple (0,1), the renaming of the 0 node to 3 should also change the edge to (3,1).

Comment: oh yea that happens automatically when you use the built in function to change node name https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html

Comment: I added a more in depth answer and a runable example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically any graph that you change the names / labels of the nodes is isomorphic to the original graph and different from it. The reason there does not exist a built in function to do that is because it's trivial and not really usable. For example:

```py
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.DiGraph()
nx.add_path(G1, [1, 2, 3, 4], weight=1)

G_iso = G1.copy()

mapping = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c',
    4: 'd'
}

G_iso = nx.relabel_nodes(G_iso, mapping)

print(f"{nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G_iso)=}")
```

Outputs:

```
nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G_iso)=True
```

Hope that helps.